# Failed to find Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Trying to install Vagrant on Windows 7 X64 with installer from Vagrant - *vagrant_1.7.0.msi*

Installation goes fine, however unable to use vagrant. On any command, for example `vagrant -v` the below is shown:
`Failed to find Vagrant!`

What I did:

1. Googled. Only 1 link with such an error on github regarding to installer. Not sure if this is relevant.
2. Checked that vagrant in PATH. Yes it is. Otherwise it would not start at all.
3. Reinstalled, and repaired - few times.

All the above with no luck. Any idea where to dig?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just to add my own version of this problem too:

- i installed version 1.7.0
- error message after a "vagrant up": "Failed to find Vagrant!"
- checked paths, other environment variables in win7, should work..

so i uninstalled it and installed an older version (1.6.5)

and yes, the older version solved the problem.
i got it from their official website: https://www.vagrantup.com/download-archive/v1.6.5.html

i guess the problem was in this file:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-installers/blob/master/substrate/launcher/main.go

Comment: It looks like "gems" folder changed its location with recent version.

Comment: Looks like it's an issue that's already logged against the github repo

- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4924

Comment: @daniel-h Thank you. Downgrade solved the issue. Seems something with the gems location as ljaded mentioned.

Comment: [Vagrant 1.7.1 has been released](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4924#issuecomment-66808666) and this bug was fixed

Answer (score 3):

Same Issue on Windows 7 64.

Downgraded back to Vagrant 1.6.5

Comment: Just to be helpful, to downgrade (on windows 7), run `vagrant_1.7.0.msi` again, choose the option to remove. Then download `vagrant_1.6.5.msi`( https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vagrant/vagrant_1.6.5.msi ) and run it. You may need to restart between.

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through the installation instructions on vagrant side listed here :
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/installation/index.html

This is what I see  listed at their site:

> The installer will automatically add vagrant to your system path so that it is available in terminals. If it is not found, please try logging out and logging back in to your system (this is particularly necessary sometimes for Windows).

Please try running it from Git Bash too and let me know if it works for you.

And if you still run into issues, try using an older version of vagrant https://www.vagrantup.com/download-archive/v1.6.5.html

Comment: I did. Everything I could. As turned out that is an issue with vagrant itself https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4924

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant 1.7.1 should fix this. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4924#issuecomment-66808666